# Set theoretic realism

Tags: logic, set-theory, philosophy

What are the main contemporary arguments for and against realism about set theory?

Comment: What is the sense of 'reality' that one is supposed to ascribe to set theory? This seems more a philosophical question than a mathematical one.

Comment: I'm not very good at such discussions, but it seems to me that once you want to do math (involving a formal definition of integers and arithmetic), you need to have something; do we have anything better then axiomatic set theory? It is the result of some *evolution* of formalization of "computing, analysis, equation solving, etc" that was used practically in other sciences.

Comment: See Gödel's *What is Cantor's Continuum Problem*. It is well known that Gödel was a realist in set theory. In that article he defends that position. I'm sure he does so in many others too. but just so I understand, you've came forward as a platonist and you're being asked to defend your position, is that it?

Comment: `"Does one write such criticism off as valid skepticism?"` The fact that there is non consensus among mathematicians (who actually thing about this) shows that the skepticism is valid.

Comment: Yes - platoism with a small p. But, the problem is more than just platoism. That is just the existence of abstract objects. The question is what kind of abstract object set theory is. The question I have been asked is whether it is a nonexistent object (i.e. a purple dragon) or an abstract object that can be defended by some theory of truth (i.e. 1).

Comment: What does "can be defended by some theory of truth" mean here? What boat is $1$ in that makes it less of a problem than sets?

Comment: Are you familiar with Quine's criterion of ontological commitment (see his paper *On What There Is* if not)? The arguments to accept the sets are the arguments for accepting the theory that quantifies over them.

Comment: @user155194 `"Clearly, I will need to present both sides (citing the relevant exemplars of the critics and the proponents of the ontological existence of set theory). Where to begin?"` Have you looked at some philosophy of mathematics books? I can think of two which give a general overview of the status of things.

Comment: Mathematics is a game with certain rules (which, by the way, have always been evolving over time). What reality do you speak of? Has anyone seen, e.g., an infinite-dimensional Banach space? Mathematical objects are no more real than characters in a work of fiction. Some mathematical objects are clearly abstractions of real-world phenomena; others are not. Only when mathematics is applied to real-world problems (e.g., in physics), can one raise the question as to whether these rules are "adequate"---in the sense that this game can make predictions about reality.

Comment: @Vladimir I share your view. This is called formalism/deductivism. But it's far from being the standard view. A platonist claims that mathematics exist as an independent reality and we're just trying to discover it.

Comment: @GitGud The romantic (and most probably best) part of my soul wishes for mathematics to be real (even if in some parallel reality). But common sense says that, alas, we are just playing a game, and a very intellectually challenging one, as far as games are concerned. As to plato(n)ists' claims, I guess even plato(n)ists would agree that they are no more than beliefs, and I remember having been taught that beliefs are not (should not be) part of science.

Comment: Why not counter with skepticism about *concrete* objects? The moral of the story of the Ship of Theseus is that when we talk about a physical object persisting through time, we're imposing on it a unity that is not "given" to us by experience. I believe Kant made this point. So...if it's okay to posit enduring physical objects in order to make sense of the world, even though nature only delivers one perceptual experience after another, why can't we posit abstract objects if that, too, helps? The burden is on the skeptic to say why we mustn't.

Comment: @Vladimir: Well, platonism is not a hypothesis of the natural sciences, it's a philosophical position. And the reason to accept a philosophical position is that the reasons for it are markedly better than the alternative. Platonists don't just accept platonism because of a strong feeling they have; they typically accept it because they find the reasons to do so compelling. Personally, I would have described myself as a formalist about six years ago, but now reject that position.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: This does not alter the fact that platonism (as well as formalism) is no more than a system of beliefs. It is actually a personal matter what reasons one finds more compelling. But, philosophical issues aside, how does one or the other belief help one when solving scientific problems? My answer is: it does not. The best proof is that mathematicians with various philosopical beliefs can work very well together. Thus, for me, there is no reason to choose a more complicated version (platonism) over a simpler one (formalism). This is a matter of personal belief as well:)

Comment: That's funny, because it's actually simplicity that biases me towards platonism :p And I'm not sure I agree with "just a matter of personal belief" in the sense in which you seem to intend it; the connotation seems to be that there's no objective reason one should prefer one viewpoint over the other, and I would strongly disagree with that. You are of course right that it makes precious little difference in practice; myself, though, I'm a philosopher disguised as a mathematician...

Comment: I changed the title (which borders in nonsense and anyway is unrelated to the body of the question) into something that actually tells us what the question is about.

Comment: IMHO, most set theory axioms are quite "realistic", e.g. those used to infer the existence of subsets, power sets, Cartesian product, pairwise union, choice and other functions. It seems to me that almost all of mathematics can be derived from them. Then there are other, more "special purpose" axioms that don't often come up in mathematics, e.g. axiom of regulatory, infinity, large cardinals.

Comment: I've rolled back because your addition is really a different question unrelated to this one. Ask it as a separate question. Otherwise you are likely to not get any proper answers, and instead receive a poor potpourri that does not address fully neither the current version nor the new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One difficulty here is that it isn't clear what counts as "realism" about set theory.

Compare, just for a start, these two views:

1. There is One True Universe of Sets, out there in Plato's heaven, and our aim as mathematicians is to explore that universe as best we can. And a claim like the Continuum Hypothesis, for example, is just plain true or plain false about that One True Universe (the snag is our best attempts to settle the matter by making plausible-seeming assumptions about that universe haven't got us in reach of an answer). Still, there is a Real Fact of the Matter about which way it goes with the Continuum Hypothesis, or with any other coherent question we can ask about sets.
2. A theory like ZFC has lots of models, there's lots of different set theoretic universes (a "multiverse", if you like, not One True Universe). These different set theoretic universes are all as good as each other -- and in some CH is true, and in some CH isn't. These universes of ZFC-governed sets are all equally "real" -- and then there are other worlds of sets where, for example, New Foundations rules (assuming that theory is consistent).

Now, both views might be called species of realism. The first may have been Gödel's view (and there are still some who think, yes, there is a Fact of the Matter about whether CH is true, we just haven't yet found a way of settling which). The second view is in one way, you might think, a stronger form of realism (instead of believing in One True Universe of sets, it believes in *lots* of different set universes); but in other ways it makes weaker claims -- CH lacks a determinate truth value, but only is true or false relative to a particular model.

But anyway, the present point is that when one asks about arguments for and against set-theoretic realism, it is obviously going to matter which kind of realism or anti-realism is in question (and we've only touched on two varieties).

---

A footnote. Mauro mentions some key readings. Maddy's book is probably not an easy read for non-philosophers: but for an account of what's at stake in that book -- she explores in particular a positions she calls  Thin Realism, which is different again from both the positions mentioned above -- you could look at  the review I wrote with Luca Incurvati, [available here](http://mind.oxfordjournals.org/content/121/481/195.full.pdf?keytype=ref&%2520ijkey=5jHdu6tvvzwQkDn). And I'd add that it could be worth looking too at the opening of Michael Potter's justly admired book *Set Theory and Its Philosophy*

Comment: (As an aside, Holmes has a proof of Con(NF) that seems to be pretty solid, so we're nearly able to stop adding those parentheticals :p)

Answer (score 5):

You can see :

> Penelope Maddy, [Defending the Axioms: On the Philosophical Foundations of Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199671486) (2013)
>
> Richard Tieszen, [After Godel: Platonism and Rationalism in Mathematics and Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019960620X) (2011)

and some chapters of :

> George Boolos, [Logic, Logic, and Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067453767X) (1998), mainly Ch.8 : *Must We Believe in Set Theory ?* (page 120-on).